# jQuery Traversing with .not

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I've coded a column of several red boxes each containing a smaller grey box. When a grey box gets clicked, I want all red boxes to animate left by 100px, except for the red box containing the grey box that was clicked. I know that I need to use some form of `.not()` to exclude the child of the red box that I want remaining stationary, however I'm not sure what to put inside of the `.not()` parentheses.

http://jsbin.com/taforuxu/2/edit

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.foo').click(function() {
     $('.blah').not(???).animate({left:'100px'});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $('.foo').click(function () {
      alert("a");
      $('.blah').not($(this).parent()).animate({
          left: '60px'
      });
  });
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/Sw5Ax/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to exclude the `blah` that's the parent node of the `foo` being clicked, so

```
$('.blah').not(this.parentNode).animate({left:'100px'});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/taforuxu/7/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I had it reversed in my (deleted) answer, +1 to you :)